# Wand Image from PDF doesn't apply resizing

Tags: python-3.x, thumbnails, wand

I'm using wand in a Django project, to generate a thumbnail from different kind of files, e.g pdf, all the thumbnail generation process is done in memory, the source file is get from a request and the thumbnail is saved to a temporary file, then Django FileFiled saves the image in the correct path, but the thumbnail generated keeps the initial size, this is my code:

```
with image.Image(file=self.content.file, format="png") as im: # self.content is a django model FileField didn't saved yet, so the file inside is still in memory (from the request)
    im.resize(200, 200)
    name = self.content.file.name
    self.temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    im.save(file=self.temp)
    self.thumbnail = InMemoryUploadedFile(self.temp, None, name + ".png", 'image/png', 0, 0, None)  # then self.thumnail as FileField saves the image
```

Do you have any idea what happen? could be a bug? I've already reported it as issue on wand github page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the fact that your PDF has more than one page. If you only resize the first page (which is the one you want to display), it works. Try adding the following line after your `with` statement:

```
im = image.Image(image=im.sequence[0])
```

But I agree with you that your version should work as well.